# Reduction rule for IF?

Tags: logic, programming-languages, lambda-calculus, term-rewriting, operational-semantics

I'm working through Simon Peyton Jones' "The Implementation of Functional Programming Languages" and on page 20 I see:

```
IF TRUE ((λp.p) 3) ↔ IF TRUE 3         (per β red)   (1)
                   ↔ (λx.IF TRUE 3 x)  (per η red)   (2)
                   ↔ (λx.3)                          (3)
```

Step 1 to 2 is explained as η-conversion. But from 2 to 3 it says "The final step is the reduction rule for IF." I'm not sure what this reduction rule is.

Answer (score 10):

The reduction rule you ask for is the usual one for IF statements. It consists of two computation rules and one context rule:

> - $\text{IF TRUE}$ $a$ $b$ $\to$ $a$
> - $\text{IF FALSE}$ $a$ $b$ $\to$ $b$
> - $\dfrac{a\to a'}{\text{IF}~a\ b\ c\to \text{IF}~a'\ b\ c}$

In both the call-by-value (strict) and call-by-need (lazy) settings, both $a$ and $b$ can be arbitrary expressions. They need not be values.

Rules of this kind, that reduce specific functions (here `IF`), are often called delta rules.

Now, the reason step (2) above is necessary is so that the reduction rules for $\text{IF}$ can apply. $\text{IF}$ requires 3 arguments, but in the original term it has only two, so cannot be reduced. ($\text{IF}$ is being partially applied, just
like any function in Haskell. This means that only part of its arguments need to be supplied.) The use of $\eta$-expansion provides the additional argument, without changing the semantics.

Comment: I would add 
`IF a b c -> IF a' b c with a-> a'`

Comment: Yes but should η-conversion not be adding conditions? It seems that going from **IF TRUE 3** to **λx.IF TRUE 3 x** (excuse my omission of **x** on the original post) -- if then used in the next step as conforming to IF reduction -- is not exactly honest, because we added the **x** just to be the quasi ELSE half. For example, what if the problem been **IF FALSE 3**? Could we have η-conversion-ed it into **λx.IF FALSE 3 x**? Then step 3 would have been **λx.x**, which doesn't seem right... Odd, this. The point was to prove **IF TRUE ((λp.p) 3)** is equivalent to **(λx.3)** This has me confused.

Comment: @galaxybeing: I've added a a comment regarding why you use $\eta$-expansion. Ultimately, it is so that *IF* has two arguments, and therefore its reduction rules can be applied.

Comment: @galaxybeing `IF FALSE 3` **is** equivalent to  `\x -> IF FALSE 3 x` (assuming partial application of `IF` is allowed). `IF FALSE 3` needs one more argument to be reduced to a value; applying it to `x` yields `IF FALSE 3 x`, which reduces to simply `x`. So `IF FALSE 3` is indeed equivalent to `\x -> x`, as long as we're using the untyped lambda calculus; if you try this out in Haskell (by defining a function `if' :: Bool -> a -> a` so you can partially apply it) then you get the `id` function specialised to whatever type Haskell infers for the `3`.